# Complex cross domain scripting

Tags: javascript, cross-domain, jsonp

I have the following scenario, a user on domain1.com opens a new window on domain2.com. Domain2 contains a pretty complex web app where the user can browse and select documents. When the user is done searching for the right document he want's to send the select document back do domain1 and close the window. Is this possible in any way? I guess JSONP is not good enough because the response is not immediate?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [message API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.postMessage) to communicate between the windows

There is [a library](http://easyxdm.net/wp/) for cross-browser implementation.

Comment: Indeed. Forget JSON or JSONP for something like that. You need to be able to send and receive messages. This is the way to go.

Comment: I need to at least have support for IE 8 and all modern browsers. Is this chart up to date? http://cl.ly/Ftka

Comment: @Marcus don't forget that you can mark answers as "accepted" by clicking on the checkmark next to them if they have helped solve your problem.